# Creating REST api for EJB

Tags: java, rest, jboss, ejb

I'm using JBoss 9.x Application Server and I want to create a REST api to communicate with my EJBs.
I created two classes PlayerRestApi and PlayerEJB and deploy it to wildfly, but when I requested /player the response is always 404.

**Note:** I will post the PlayerRestApi class with a dummy return.

PlayerRestApi code:

```
@Local
@Path("/player")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class PlayerRestApi{
    PlayerEJB player;

    @GET
    public Map<String, String> getPlayer(){
        Map<String, String> r = new HashMap<String,String>();
        r.put("Name","Ronaldo");
        return r;
    }
}
```

When I tried this route, localhost: http://localhost:28070/appname/player
Wildfly returns 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was deploying a jar file instead of a war file, so the wildfly returns 404.
The code it's correct and works.

**Note** This version of Wildfly Application Server doesn't need the web.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use for example RESTEasy libraries, I don´t know if wildfly has it out of the box (is a jboss library), you can use Jersey too.

¿Have you updated your web.xml in order to define the RESTEasy servlets?

Here is an example (you have to put your class in resteasy.resources)

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>your JAX-RS annotated class</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I think wildfly 9.0+ doesn't need the web.xml file, it's correct?

Comment: Hi, I did not use wildfly 9.0+ yet. I don´t know if there is an instance ready to serve rest services out of the box...